# Apache/webdav: "client used wrong authentication scheme"

Tags: apache, ms-word, windows-10, webdav

I have the following in my apache config (gentoo Linux amd64) - running over ssl:

```
Alias /files /home/apache/files
<Directory /home/apache/files>
Dav on
Dav filesystem
AuthType Basic
Require user username
AuthName "Restricted site"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/htpasswd
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

When I access this site on Windows 10 from a remote computer, I get these messages in my logs when I open a file in MS Word:

```
[auth_basic:error] [pid 8486] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx] AH01614: client used wrong authentication scheme:
```

I have fail2ban installed on my server, and it bans my work site after I've opened a few files

Is there some change in my config that would stop this from happening, or is the problem on the remote site?